# How do I Redirect to Login page using PHP

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I am trying to redirect my php login page so that if user is authorised, it goes to a page (r_index.php) and if the user isn't authorised they go back to the login page (login.html).

This is my code:

```
    <?php  
if ("password"=="$password") { // Start the condition  ?>  
<a href="r_index.php">Manage classes</a>  
<?php     } // End the condition ?>     
<?php if ("password"=="") { ?>     
<a href="login.html">Login</a>     
<?php } 
?>.
```

What am I doing wrong? How should I resolve it?

Comment: That depends entirely on what the problem is, do you get any errors?

Comment: `if ("password"=="")` this will never be true

Comment: I had no errors, it just would not redirect. Do I need to link it to my database to look up whether the individual has a login in order to authorise them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your code with this:

```
<?php  
 if ("password"== $password) { 
    header("location:r_index.php");  
 }
 else if ($password=="") {   
    header("location:login.html");     
 } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect you should use:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/r_index.php');
```

in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$accessGranted = false;

if($password == 'password') {
   $accessGranted = true;
}

if($accessGranted) {
   header('Location: r_index.php');
}
else {
   header('Location: login.html');
}
exit;
```

Comment: This looks good, however when I enter an incorrect password, the incorrect password message comes up but never directs to the login page (login.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Actually your syntax is wrong, else there is no problem of using HTML inside php. It will work well and good.

Just make sure not to put your variable inside quotes, and change the statement as follows:

```
if($password=="password")
```

and

```
if($Password==" ")
```